# multiple threads virtual address space?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

I am having a question regarding multithreading.

Does multiple threads of a given application share the same virtual address space? or does each thread has its own virtual address space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each process has its own virtual address space.
All the threads spawned within a process share the virtual address space of the process.

This is the reason that all the threads within the same process can access global variables defined within that process without any special mechanism, while processes need some sort of Inter-Process Communication(IPC) mechanism to share data variables.